# R - Easy significant test on 2 dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, significance

I am stucking a simple statistical comparism of 2 dataframes. Both dataframes consist of different kind of observations (columns) and the observation days (rows). I counted the number of occurrences for each day and each case. I dont have the same number of observation days, the observations took place under different conditions and I want to find out if there is a significant difference between those two dataframes. So basically I want to compare Case1 of df1 with Case1 of df2. For that I calculated the number of occurrences per day of each dataframe and compared them (in%).

In reality I have thousands of these dataframes and all have different number of rows.

My problem is now, how can I get an idea of which of the results are significant? How can I see if only 9 day of observation is too less to be significant?

I tried to perform a Chi-Square test, is that the right thing to do?

Here is Dataframe 1:

```
structure(list(Case1 = c(17L, 9L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 13L, 
7L, 17L, 9L, 11L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 17L, 7L, 
13L, 12L, 10L, 16L, 7L, 6L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 
9L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 19L, 14L, 
10L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 
12L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 
4L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 17L, 16L, 9L, 16L, 12L, 
9L, 10L, 14L, 6L, 17L, 14L, 14L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 15L, 12L, 11L, 
15L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 15L, 9L, 8L, 14L, 15L, 20L, 8L, 
12L, 12L, 19L, 10L, 18L, 6L, 14L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 13L, 12L, 10L, 
15L, 11L, 17L, 12L, 8L, 15L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 14L, 9L, 6L, 18L, 5L, 
8L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 4L), Case2 = c(17L, 9L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 11L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 
20L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 15L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 14L, 6L, 6L, 12L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 15L, 
9L, 11L, 10L, 14L, 13L, 10L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 8L, 11L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
2L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 15L, 
12L, 8L, 15L, 11L, 7L, 9L, 13L, 6L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 10L, 10L, 
9L, 14L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 
13L, 13L, 16L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 13L, 10L, 16L, 6L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 
17L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 15L, 10L, 17L, 12L, 8L, 12L, 8L, 9L, 13L, 
12L, 9L, 6L, 13L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 
6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 
3L), Case3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 0L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Case1", "Case2", "Case3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-175L))
```

Here is Dataframe 2:

```
structure(list(Case1 = c(9L, 11L, 10L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 13L), 
    Case2 = c(7L, 10L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 8L), Case3 = c(2L, 1L, 
    2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L)), .Names = c("Case1", "Case2", "Case3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: hey you might needa properly define the aim. You cannot just test between 2 matrices. There has to be a hypothesis, for example, the distribution of case1, case 2 and case 3 are similar for dataframe 1 and dataframe 2.

Comment: You can sum up the colSums and make a 2x3 contingency table and do chi-sq.. this is a crude test for the above hypothesis mentioned